# Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

Tags: 8

I am getting the following error on *.../checkout/ID/order_information* page after submitting payment details for *Review*.

> Exception: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed in serialize() (line 14 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Serialization/PhpSerialize.php).

I have tried to catch the exception with a `try/catch` block, but it  always gives that fatal error, if I unchecked *My billing information is the same as my shipping information* checkbox in the *Payment information* form.

I am using my custom payment method module for payment. Where should I look in the code to find what is causing the fatal error?

__construct() method :-

```
public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager, PaymentTypeManager $payment_type_manager, PaymentMethodTypeManager $payment_method_type_manager, TimeInterface $time) {
parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $entity_type_manager, $payment_type_manager, $payment_method_type_manager, $time);

  if ($this->getMode() === 'test') {
    $url = "url given here";
  }
  else {
    $url = "url given here";
  }

  try {
    $this->soapClient = new SoapClient($url);
  }
  catch (SoapFault $e) {
    throw new PaymentGatewayException($e->getMessage());
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a __construct() method of your class? If so, please add it to the post. It may be causing your issue.

Comment: `PhpSerialize.php` is drupal's `core` file, no construct method  for `PhpSerialize` class

Comment: No, in your custom module

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my question

Comment: This is probably because you are adding (possibly indirectly) something to a form that can't be serialized. In case it's your custom payment method class I suggest refactoring so the soap client is initialized lazily instead of in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this comes from loading a connection in the SOAP client, and storing it in memory with `$this->soapClient`. The problem is that the soap client cannot be serialized. Serialization is the process of turning something into a string, generally so it can be stored in a databse or a file or something, to be retrieved later. The SOAP connection is not something that can be stored, which is why you are facing the issue.

You could potentially store the SOAP client in the construct method, then make the connection using the client when you actually need it. I'm guessing that the client, without a connection, can probably be serialized. I may be wrong though, and you may need to call the soap client dynamically every time you need it.

Comment: taking out `$this->soapClient = new SoapClient($url);` from construct method has fixed this issue for now

Comment: Thank you for the hint of looking around my constructor. While writing a custom form controller extending ConfigFormBase commenting out temporarily all the lines setting a value to object attributes has solved this serialization issue of my Ajax requests. Now I reorganize my code to inject dependencies differently.

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding `use DependencySerializationTrait;` to the class.

You could also try disabling caching if you can do without: `$form_state->disableCache();`